# customizing django admin ChangeForm template / adding custom content

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm able to insert (lame) static text onto the change form admin page, but I'd really like it to use the context of the current object being edited!

For instance, I want to format on the MyObject change form a URL to include the ID from a ForeignKey connected object (`obj`) as a link.

My admin objects:

```
class MyObjectChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyObject
        fields = ('field1', 'obj',)

class MyObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyObjectChangeForm
    list_display = ('field1', 'obj')
    def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
        self.change_form_template = 'admin/my_change_form.html'
        extra = {'lame_static_text': "something static",}
        context.update(extra)
        return super(MyObjectAdmin, self).render_change_form(request,
            context, *args, **kwargs)
```

My template `templates/admin/my_change_form.html`:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block form_top %}
    {{ lame_static_text }}
    <a href="http://example.com/abc/{{ adminform.data.obj.id }}?"/>View Website</a>
{% endblock %}
```

The `{{adminform.data.obj.id}}` call obviously doesn't work, but I'd like something along those lines.

How do I insert dynamic context from the current object into the admin change form?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add your extra context in [change_view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view)

```py
class MyObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # A template for a very customized change view:
    change_form_template = 'admin/my_change_form.html'

    def get_dynamic_info(self):
        # ...
        pass

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['osm_data'] = self.get_dynamic_info()
        return super(MyObjectAdmin, self).change_view(
            request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context,
        )
```

Comment: This could be helpful, but can't tell. Is `get_dynamic_info()` suppose to just perform database queries arbitrarily? That's not what I want. I only want the data for the object in question which (obviously) has to be availiable somehow because it's a change form (implying the object is already in the database). Also, it would be accessed in the template as `{{osm_data}}` ? Not clear what you're suggesting as the actual solution here.

Comment: You have the access to `object_id` for which the change view is rendering. So you can query that object and get its related field id and send that as `extra_context`. And yes you can use these extra context in template as `{{osm_data}}`.

Answer (score 15):

I believe the magic variable you seek is 'original', this contains the python object the change form is editing:

```
<a href="http://example.com/abc/{{ original.id }}?"/>View Website</a>
```