# How to pass custom data to a django template?

Tags: django, django-admin

I like to pass some custom data to a template in django admin. How do I access `myData` in the sample below?

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_object(self, request, object_id, form_field=None):
        obj = super().get_object(request, object_id, form_field)
        self.myData = MyModel.objects.filer(id=obj.myData_ID) 
        return obj
```

In the template:

```
{% for p in myData %}
    <p>{{p}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer StackOverflow: [customizing django admin ChangeForm template / adding custom content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845982/customizing-django-admin-changeform-template-adding-custom-content/39848376#39848376)

You may try this:

```
 class MyObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

     # A template for a very customized change view:
     change_form_template = 'admin/my_change_form.html'

     def get_dynamic_info(self):
         # ...
         pass

     def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['osm_data'] = self.get_dynamic_info()
        return super(MyObjectAdmin, self).change_view(
            request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context,
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it like this.  I haven't tried

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_object(self, request, object_id, form_field=None):
        obj = super().get_object(request, object_id, form_field)
        return obj

    def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
        context['myData'] = MyModel.objects.filer(id=obj.myData_ID) 
        return super(MyAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, args, kwargs)
```

Comment: Passing data using `context["myData"]` works. But how I can access the model in the line `id=obj.myData_ID`? I tried `self.model` but then I got a `django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute`.